# What is port 8000 used for in play

Tags: playframework

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
The above string is spewed out during Play Framework initialization, how is this port used?

Comment: what do u mean by how !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically your application will run on port 9000 And As i know it will listen for client debugger on port 8000 and socketAttach will use dt_socket as transport